# Pattern matching vector

Tags: list, vector, sml, smlnj

Is it possible in SML to pattern match against a vector like you can with a list?

With a list I can simply do this:

```
fun foo ([]) = 0
  | foo (l::ls) = 1 + foo (ls);
```

How can I do that for a vector?

I tried `fun foo (Vector.fromList([])) = 0` but that gives me this error:

`Vector.fromList is not a constructor Found near Vector.fromList ([])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, no.

Lists have their value constructors, `::` and `nil` exposed [as part of their interface](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html), allowing for pattern matching. Vectors [do not](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/vector.html).

This probably stems from the fact, that lists are rather easily implemented using datatypes in-language, while providing constant-time access vectors lends itself more to an in-compiler implementation using native arrays.

Note, that the reason you cannot pattern-match on `Vector.fromList` is, that it is not a *value constructor*, but rather a function. (Unlike `::` and `nil`.)

Answer (score 3):

Not regularly. However, a couple of SML implementations -- in particular, SML/NJ -- support *vector literals* as a language extension. Those can also be used in patterns:

```
val v = #[1, 2, 3]
val #[x, y, _] = v
```

However, vectors are not inductively constructed, so you cannot match head and tail like with lists. You can only match vectors with known and fixed length, like above.